# Django. Empty Query list while adding a model object through the shell

Tags: django, django-models

I have made a class in my apps models.py file looking like this:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

Through the shell i want to add and instance of this class to the database
i enter the shell through the command line using

```
python manage.py shell
```

Then I create the object

```
>>> from polls.models import Question
>>> Question
<class 'polls.models.Question'>
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> q = Question (question_text='Million Dollar Question', pub_date=timezone.now())
>>> q
<Question: Million Dollar Question>
```

When looking to see all objects for Question is get an empty query list, how come?

```
>>> Question.objects.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

Answer (score 1):

After you created your question

```
q = Question (question_text='Million Dollar Question', pub_date=timezone.now())
```

you have the instance available in memory, but not saved into the database - this is why `Question.objects.all()` does not returns it. To  save it call `save()` on the instance.

```
q.save()
```

Django provides a method on the [ObjectManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#manager-names) that does both steps for you:

```
q = Ouestion.objects.create(question_text='Million Dollar Question', pub_date=timezone.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't save the question.

```
q.save()
```